# Attaching snake-tail in snake game (Python:pygame)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm stumped after tying to attach a snake tail img, can someone explain a possible way to attach it so after each block is added it stays at the end.

The snake tail is variable tail under ##Snake Images

```
import pygame
import random
import time


pygame.init()

White = (255,255,255)
Black = (0,0,0)
Green = (0,155,0)
Lgreen = (219,255,219)
Red = (255,0,0)

Dwidth = 800
Dheight = 600

GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Dwidth,Dheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

##Other Images
icon = pygame.image.load('apple.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

Logo = pygame.image.load('Snakelogo.png')

##Apple Images
appleimg = pygame.image.load('apple.png')

##Snake Images
img = pygame.image.load('snake.png')
tail = pygame.image.load('snakebot.png')


Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

blockS = 20
AppleThickness = 30

FPS = 17.5

direction = "right"

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

def pause():
    paused = True
    message("Paused",
            Black,
            -100,
            size="large")
    message("Press SPACE again to continue or Q to quit.",
            Black,
            25)
    pygame.display.update()

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    paused = False

                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        Clock.tick(5)


def score(score):
    text = smallfont.render("Score: "+str(score), True, Black)
    GameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])

def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = round(random.randrange(0,Dwidth-AppleThickness))#/10.0)*10.0
    randAppleY = round(random.randrange(0,Dheight-AppleThickness))#/10.0)*10.0

    return randAppleX,randAppleY
randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        GameDisplay.fill(Lgreen)
        GameDisplay.blit(Logo,[0,100,800,170])

        message("The objective of the game is to eat red apples,",
                Black,
                -30)
        message("the more apples you eat the longer you get and",
                Black,
                10)
        message("if you run into yourself or the edges you die.",
                Black,
                50)
        message("Press C to play, SPACE to pause, or Q to quit.",
                Black,
                180)
        pygame.display.update()
        Clock.tick(15)

def snake(blockS,snakeList):

    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img, 270)

    if direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img, 90)

    if direction == "up":
        head = img

    if direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(img, 180)

    GameDisplay.blit(head,(snakeList[-1][0],snakeList[-1][1]))

    for XnY in snakeList[:-1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay,Green,[XnY[0],XnY[1],blockS, blockS])

def text_objects(text,color,size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text,True,color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text,True,color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text,True,color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message(msg,color,y_displace=0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (Dwidth/2),(Dheight/2) +y_displace
    GameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)



def gameloop():
    global direction

    direction = "right"
    GameEX = False
    GameOver = False

    Hor_X = Dwidth/2
    Ver_Y = Dheight/2

    MoveS = 10
    MoveDU = 0

    snakeList = []
    snakeLength = 1

    randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not GameEX:
        if GameOver == True:
            message("Game Over",
                    Red,
                    y_displace=-50,
                    size="large")
            message("Press C to play again or Q to Quit", Black,50, size = "medium")
            pygame.display.update()


        while GameOver == True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    GameEX = True
                    GameOver = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        GameEX = True
                        GameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameloop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                GameEX = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    MoveS = -blockS
                    MoveDU = 0
                    direction = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    MoveS = blockS
                    MoveDU = 0
                    direction = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    MoveDU = -blockS
                    MoveS = 0
                    direction = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    MoveDU = blockS
                    MoveS = 0
                    direction = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    pause()

        if Hor_X >= Dwidth or Hor_X < 0 or Ver_Y >= Dheight or Ver_Y < 0:
            GameOver = True


        Hor_X += MoveS
        Ver_Y += MoveDU


        GameDisplay.fill(Lgreen)

        GameDisplay.blit(appleimg,(randAppleX, randAppleY))

        snakeHead = []
        snakeHead.append(Hor_X)
        snakeHead.append(Ver_Y)
        snakeList.append(snakeHead)

        if len(snakeList) > snakeLength:
            del snakeList[0]

        for eachSegment in snakeList[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == snakeHead:
                GameOver = True

        snake(blockS,snakeList)

        score(snakeLength-1)

        pygame.display.update()



        if Hor_X > randAppleX and Hor_X < randAppleX + AppleThickness or Hor_X + blockS > randAppleX and Hor_X + blockS < randAppleX + AppleThickness:
            if Ver_Y > randAppleY and Ver_Y < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                snakeLength += 1

            elif Ver_Y + blockS > randAppleY and Ver_Y + blockS < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                snakeLength += 1



        Clock.tick(FPS)




    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameloop()
```

inserting this into the snake function is as close as Ive gotten to attaching it to the end~

```
for XnY in snakeList[0]:
    GameDisplay.blit(tail,(snakeList[0][0],snakeList[0][1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just increased my snakeLength to 2 and it solved my problem after adding

```
for XnY in snakeList[0]:
    GameDisplay.blit(tail,(snakeList[0][0],snakeList[0][1]))
```

into the snake function.